Why does audio from the start of a movie play quietly after I play a movie in VLC?
Is there a command that will show what processes are outputting audio?
Scenario: I play a movie in VLC. Near the end, I pause it, or even exit VLC. Quiet audio from the start of the same movie is  now playing this continues for 5-10 minutes, even when I use Force Quit and kill all apps.
I use ps aux | grep -i vlc, and likewise for quicktime, and find nothing. The audio continues to play.
